# Having some trouble php connection string to a mssql server

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I been working game that use MSSQL but I have been having trouble with the connection as it keep coming back as `undefined`.

I don't know much about PHP and a friend helped me setup the server.
It's Apache 2.2

```
$serveruser ="user";
$serverPass = "pass";
$server = "server";

$con = mssql_connect($server, $serveruser, $serverPass);

if (!$con)
    die('Could not connect:');
```

Comment: What error message are you getting? Are you sure the credentials are correct? Please post more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
$selected = mysql_select_db("database name",$dbhandle);
if($selected){
    echo "buuraaaa.....my database is selected \o/";
}
else    {
  echo "ohh,,,no its not selected";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic syntax of connection is :-

```
 mssql_connect("localhost<host name>", "<username>", "<password>");
```

check your hostname, username and password.